# Compare intersections between lists of set and its partition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have 100 lists, each list contains many sets. For example,

```
L1 = [{2,7},{2,7,8},{2,3,6,7},{1,2,4,5,7}]      
L2 = [{3,6},{1,3,4,6,7},{2,3,5,6,8}]      
L3 = [{2,5,7,8},{1,2,3,5,7,8}, {2,4,5,6,7,8}] 
....
L100=[{},{},{}]
```

I need to find intersections between each set of L1, L2, L3, ...L100, i.e., $Intersect(L) = \lbrace\bigcap e | e \in \lbrace L1,...,L100 \rbrace \rbrace $

Now, if I partition these 100 lists into smaller groups, e.g., 3 groups (number of lists in each group may be different, but 1 list just belongs to 1 group)

- Group 1: From L1 to L33
- Group 2: From L34 to L66
- Group 3: From L67 to L100

Then, I calculate

$Intersect(L1) = \lbrace\bigcap e | e \in \lbrace L1,...L33 \rbrace \rbrace$

$Intersect(L2) = \lbrace\bigcap e | e \in \lbrace L34,...L66 \rbrace \rbrace$

$Intersect(L3) = \lbrace\bigcap e | e \in \lbrace L67,...L100 \rbrace \rbrace$

I want to ask that the following is true?

$Intersect(L) = \lbrace\bigcap e | e \in \lbrace Intersect(L1), Intersect(L2), Intersect(L3) \rbrace \rbrace $

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure what your notation means.   Is $\lbrace\bigcap e | e \in \lbrace L1,...,L100 \rbrace \rbrace$ supposed to mean the set of all sets that are in each list, or the set of all elements that are in each set in each list, or something else?

Comment: Thank you for your care. it means (each set of L1) intersects with (each set of L2) intersects with (each set of L3) ...... intersect with (each set of L100). It is called casterian product, if I am not wrong.